# Creating resource files for coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

In compiled languages, it is often useful to move some settings into an external resource file(s) that is loaded by the code at runtime. These are just key/value pairs. This resource file can be edited w/o recompiling the code.

I find this a useful way of organizing settings. I was wondering if there was an easy way to do something similar in coffeescript. Specifically, I'd like to move a lot of the jqm settings out of the pageinit, as well as some other application specific settings into an external file(s).

I've tried searching for an answer but "resource" is too generic a word to produce useful results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple JavaScript object for this? Something like:

```
window.app.settings = {
    key: value,
    // ...
};
```

where `app` would be your application's namespace. Or in CoffeeScript:

```
@app.settings =
    key: value
    #...
```

If you have lots of settings then namespace them with sub-objects. This approach is also JSON-compatible in case you want to work with the settings in languages other than (Java|Coffee)Script.